# jquery mobile adding a list view to the page footer problem

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am trying to add a 2 selection list view to the page2 footer below.  I have the footer position fixed and the list view and links work just fine.  My problem is I can't find a way to size the list view to stretch the screen width other than by adding text.  The list view "buttons" in the footer are small and I want to control their width.  Thanks

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>jQuery Mobile Web App</title>
<link href="jquery.mobile-1.0a3.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script src="jquery-1.5.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery.mobile-1.0a3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="/phonegap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head> 
<body> 

<div data-role="page" id="page">
<div data-role="header">
    <h1>Page One</h1>
</div>
<div data-role="content">   
    <ul data-role="listview">
        <li><a href="#page2">Page Two</a></li>
        <li><a href="#page3">Page Three</a></li>
        <li><a href="#page4">Page Four</a></li>
    </ul>       
</div>
<div data-role="footer">
    <h4>Page Footer</h4>
</div>
</div>

<div data-role="page" id="page2">
<div data-role="header">
    <h1>Page Two</h1>
</div>
<div data-role="content">   
    Content     
</div>
 <div data-role="footer" align="center" data-position="fixed"  data-theme="c">   
  <ul data-role="listview" data-theme="b" data-inset="true">
    <li><a href="#page">Page One </a></li><br>
        <li><a href="#page3">Page 3</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
</div>

<div data-role="page" id="page3">
<div data-role="header">
    <h1>Page Three</h1>
</div>
<div data-role="content">   
    Content     
</div>
<div data-role="footer">
    <h4>Page Footer</h4>
</div>
</div>

<div data-role="page" id="page4">
<div data-role="header">
    <h1>Page Four</h1>
</div>
<div data-role="content">   
    Content     
</div>
<div data-role="footer">
    <h4>Page Footer</h4>
</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up adding a navbar which did what I needed.